# Dependency on 'hammerjs'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts

Tags: angular, hammer.js

I am working on an angular application with Angular CLI 11.0.2 and I am using **hammerJS** in my application to handle the swipe events.

When I compile the application, I have the following warning message:

```
Warning: F:\Programs\GoodRiddles\git\angular\src\app\config\hammerjs.config.ts depends on 'hammerjs'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

From what I could understand [here](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/issues/1255), I should replace hammerJS by an ECMA version of the library.

***My question is:***
Is there a proper way (without simply hiding the message) to fix it? Do I need to use another library instead?

If it can help, this is how I use it:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HammerGestureConfig } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import * as hammer from "hammerjs";

@Injectable()
export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    overrides = <any>{
        swipe: { direction: hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL },
        pinch: { enable: false },
        rotate: { enable: false }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add Hammerjs to allowedCommonJsDependencies in your angular.json

```
"architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
          "hammerjs" <== here
        ],...
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer Tarek. But this is precisely the answer I didn't want ^^. This will only move hammerjs in the allowed CommonJS dependencies. What I am looking for is an alternative that won't create this CommonJs dependency in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it seems you can import `hammer.js` from platform browser in this way:

```js
import { HammerModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HammerModule,
  ])
```

**Note**: as I am currently porting the application, I ignore if it works as expected.

Comment: Indeed it seems to be working as (I) expected